# Is the totient function $\varphi$ invertible?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function, arithmetic-functions, multiplicative-function

As title, is the totient function $\varphi: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ invertible?

Comment: Have you looked at any cases?  Any at all?

Comment: $\phi(77)=60=\phi(61)$, for a non-obvious example.

Comment: If we're working in the Dirichlet convolution ring, then certainly :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note that $\varphi(1)=\varphi(2)$. More generally, $\varphi(2n)=\varphi(n)$ if $n$ is odd.

So the $\varphi$-function is not one to one. It is also not onto. For if $b\gt 1$ is odd, there is no $n$ such that $\varphi(n)=b$.

**Remark:** A fairly recent result of Ford shows that for any integer $k\ge 2$, there is a number $b_k$ such that $\varphi(x)=b_k$ has exactly $k$ solutions.

It is not known whether there is any $b$ such that $\varphi(n)=b$ has exactly $1$ solution. Please see Carmichael's Conjecture for details.

So the $\varphi$-function is quite spectacularly non-invertible.